# Application Ambiguity in Untyped Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

So, untyped lambda calculus has the following formal grammar for its terms:

$$e::= x \mid \lambda x . e \mid e_1 e_2$$

Usually this is presented in some ML-esque language as (using de Bruijn indices)

```
data term = variable Nat | lambda term | apply term term
```

My question is: `apply (variable Nat) term` is syntactically valid, but the rator is just a free variable, isn't this an invalid expression? If not, what does it evaluate to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't evaluate (x t), where x is free, since evaluation ($\beta$-reduction) is usually defined in terms of substitution, but here you have neither a bound variable nor a function body for $t$ to be substituted into.

A term that cannot take a further step is called a normal form.

Comment: So `apply (variable Nat) term` *is* valid (not just syntactically, but in general), and furthermore in normal form?

Comment: @AlexNelson It's in head normal form. If `term` is in normal form then `apply (variable n) term` is in normal form. You can recognize normal forms in that if you start from every application and go left until you hit something that isn't an application, what you hit is always a variable, never a lambda.

Comment: I agree with @Gilles. And it also depends on the reduction strategy. For example, under normal order strategy it is in normal form, not just in head normal form. Under normal order strategy the leftmost, outermost term is always reduced first. That means the argument term is substituted into the function body before the argument term is reduced.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Gilles and @AntonTrunov, I greatly appreciate your insight into this matter :)